# In which loop i should put print function?

Tags: c

I'm beginner in programming. I'm working with c. My program should produce something like this:

```
> Give me a number: 4
> Pattern is:
**** *
*** **
** ***
* ****
```

My solution is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int row, c, n, t, temp;

   printf("Give me a number: ");
   scanf("%d",&n);

   temp = n;


   for ( row = 0 ; row <= n ; row++ )
   {
      for ( c = 0 ; c < temp ; c++ ){
         printf("*");

      }

      for ( t = n ; t >= temp ; t-- ){
         printf(" ");
         printf("*");
      }

      temp--;

      printf("\n");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

My code produces this when i give 4 as input:

```
**** *
*** * *
** * * *
* * * * *
 * * * * *
```

Where should i put my `printf(" ");` in order to fix this?

thank you.

Comment: There are two problems. See my answer

Comment: regarding calls to scanf() (and family)  always check the returned value (not the input/conversion target) to assure the input/conversion was successful. I.E. if( 1 != scanf("%d",&n) ) { // then scanf failed, handle error }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before the loop

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                             

int main()                                                                     
{                                                                              
   int row, c, n, t, temp;                                                     

   printf("Give me a number: ");                                               
   scanf("%d",&n);                                                             

   temp = n;                                                                   


   for ( row = 0 ; row <= n ; row++ )                                          
   {                                                                           
      for ( c = 0 ; c < temp ; c++ ){                                          
         printf("*");                                                          

      }                                                                        

      printf(" ");                                                             
      for ( t = n ; t >= temp ; t-- ){                                         
         printf("*");                                                          
      }                                                                        

      temp--;                                                                  

      printf("\n");                                                            
   }                                                                           

   return 0;                                                                   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Place `printf(" ");` outside (before) the second `for` loop.

```
for ( row = 0 ; row < n ; row++ ) // Change row <= n to row < n 
{
     for ( c = 0 ; c < temp ; c++ ){
         printf("*");
     }
     printf(" "); // Out side the loop
     for ( t = n ; t >= temp ; t-- ){
         printf("*");
     }

     temp--;
     printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things. First move the `printf("")` outside second for loop and add `n-1` to first for loop.

```
  ...
  for ( row = 0 ; row <= n-1 ; row++ ) //<---- fix
  {
      for ( c = 0 ; c < temp ; c++ ){
      printf("*");
  }

  printf(" "); //<----- fix
  for ( t = n ; t >= temp ; t-- ){
     printf("*");
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

> the following code is a suggested fix. this code works correctly for
>   all allowed values if user input
>
> note the limiting on what the user can input note the error checking
>   on both user input and on scanf()
>
> note the usage of comments to clearly indicate what is being performed
>   at each step of the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int row, c, temp;
   int n = 0; // user input number
   int t = 0; // number of trailing * to print

   while( (n<1) || (n >50) )
   {

       printf("Give me a number (1...50): ");

       if( 1 != scanf("%d",&n) )
       { // then scanf failed
           perror( "scanf for number failed" );
           exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
       } 

       // implied else, scanf successful

       if( (n<1) || (n >50) ) printf( "\n number not in range 1...50\n");
   } // end while

   temp = n;


   for ( row = 0 ; row < n ; row++ )
   { // fore each row

        // calculate number of leading * to pring
        temp = n - row;

        // print leading *
        for ( c = 0 ; c < temp ; c++ )
        { // for each * before space
            printf("*");
        }

        // print space
        printf(" ");

        // calculate number of trailing * to print
        t++;

        for ( c = 0; c < t; c++ )
        {
            printf("*");
        }

        printf("\n");
    } // end for

    return 0;
} // end function main
```

Answer (score 0):

The `printf(" ")` should be before `for ( t = n ; t >= temp ; t-- )` and
 `for ( row = 0 ; row <= n ; row++ )` should be changed to `for ( row = 0 ; row < n ; row++ )`

Your code should like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int row, c, n, t, temp;

   printf("Give me a number: ");
   scanf("%d",&n);

   temp = n;

   for ( row = 0 ; row < n ; row++ )
   {
      for ( c = 0 ; c < temp ; c++ ){
         printf("*");

      }

      printf(" ");

      for ( t = n ; t >= temp ; t-- ){
         printf("*");
      }

      temp--;

      printf("\n");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
int main()
{        
    int tmp;
    printf("\n");
    scanf("%d",&tmp);
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < tmp ; i++ )
    {           
        for (int j = 0; j <= tmp-i; j++)
            printf("*");
        printf(" ");

        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
            printf("*");
        printf("/n");           
    }
    return 0;
}
```